# Flutter: Exception caught by rendering library

Tags: flutter

A la hora de ver mi screen, aparece toda la pantalla en negro con el siguiente error: **Exception caught by rendering library**

Este es mi codigo:

```
class farmacia extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Page(
        list: fetchPost(),
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @required
  final Future<List<Farmacia>> list;
  Page({this.list});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Farmacia>>(
        future: list,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  Farmacia farmacia = snapshot.data[index];
                  return FarmaciaItem(
                    farmacia: farmacia,
                  );
                });
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }

          // By default, show a loading spinner
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
    );
  }
  }

class FarmaciaItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @required
  final Farmacia farmacia;
  FarmaciaItem({this.farmacia});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                DescriptionPlace(farmacia.title, farmacia.celular , "2923690749" , "facebook" , "instagram" , farmacia.x , farmacia.y),
                // ReviewList()
              ],
            ),
            HeaderAppBar(farmacia.imageUrl,farmacia.imageUrl2,farmacia.imageUrl3,farmacia.imageUrl4,farmacia.imageUrl5,farmacia.imageUrl6)
          ],

      ),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

Los errores son 14 y uno de ellos detalla:

**════════ (14) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The getter 'visible' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: visible**

este es otro de lo errores:

**════════ (13) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The method 'debugAssertIsValid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: debugAssertIsValid()**

Comment: Es una buena practica utilizar **UpperCamelCasek** al nombrar tus widgets, por lo tanto `farmacia` no seria correcto. Tienes algún repositorio donde pueda ver un poco mas del código.

Comment: https://github.com/emiibarra6/viviguamini/blob/Bloc/lib/negocio/ui/screen/farmacia.dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que la forma que utilizas para nombras las variables y clases puede ser un poco confuso, tienes un `StatelessWidget` llamado `farmacia`, un modelo llamado `Farmacia` y una instancia de ese modelo llamado `farmacia`.

En el widget `FarmaciaItem` utilizas un `MaterialApp` lo cual no es necesario, ya cuentas con un MaterialApp en tu `main.dart`.

> Flutter proporciona una serie de widgets que te ayudan a crear
>   aplicaciones que siguen el Material Design. Una aplicación Material
>   comienza con el widget MaterialApp que construye una serie de widgets
>   en la raíz...

`FarmaciaItem` tiene un `Stack` con dos Widgets uno arriba del otro, recuerda que con `Positioned` los puedes posicionar. Ademas de que ahora mismo estas utilizando un `ListView` para un solo `Widget`, ojo con eso.

```
class FarmaciaPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          // title: this.title,
          ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Farmacia>>(
        future: fetchPost(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Farmacia farmacia = snapshot.data[index];
                return FarmaciaItem(
                  farmacia: farmacia,
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }

          // By default, show a loading spinner
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FarmaciaItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Farmacia farmacia;
  FarmaciaItem({@required this.farmacia});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        DescriptionPlace(farmacia.title, farmacia.celular, "2923690749",
            "facebook", "instagram", farmacia.x, farmacia.y),
        HeaderAppBar(farmacia.imageUrl, farmacia.imageUrl2, farmacia.imageUrl3,
            farmacia.imageUrl4, farmacia.imageUrl5, farmacia.imageUrl6)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Déjame saber si te es util.

Comment: Gracias! Si, deberia de ser un poco mas creativo a la hora de pensar en nombres de variables.